# Would capitalism function or exist if corporations were required to be democracies?

Tags: parliament, government, corporations

**Nominations to the board**

Nominations would be done via multiple nominating committees that are affiliated with the nominating commission (electoral commission).  The committees would be different corporate political parties.  Each committee would have its own members that vote for its leadership (on committee and candidates for the board).

---

**board of directors**

The board is elected by the shareholders (one person, one vote as opposed to one share, one vote--this is actually historic).  Each candidate for the board is either independent or by political party.  Shareholders actually have a choice, as opposed to now (eg take it or leave it).

Outside Directors wouldn't exist just as it makes no sense for an outsider (eg Mongolian citizen) to be in the US Congress. Instead, an ethics and transparency commission or something could be set up.

Real debate could ensue, allowing better corporate governance.

Just as politicians are not considered civil servants, board members would not be considered employees.

The board could be a bit larger (20-50 members) as it would be purely legislative with no executive functions.  Half the seats could be at-large while the other is by geography or function (mixed member proportional representation is preferred).

The chairperson would be the equivalent of the speaker of the house (UK).  Since a "politician," an employee would assist in rules of the board and anything else needed.

---

**executive Officers (executive board)**

The President would be equivalent to the prime minister.  The Vice presidents (for finance, safety, technology, etc) would be the equivalent of cabinet ministers.  They would all sit together as an executive board and face questions from the regular/supervisory board.

---

**employees & non-executive officers**

Employees would all be corporate civil servants.  They would all get a share in the company so as to get a vote and "citizenship" (citizenship required for civil servants in countries).

The most senior civil servant would be the Chief administration officer (CAO).  Each department of the executive board would have a corresponding C-suite professional as chief civil servant for the ministry (eg Chief finance officer (CFO) for the finance department, under the political leadership of the Vice President for Finance).

---

**Redundancy & accountability**

By having professional employees run the company, with an elected board and executive that steers towards what the shareholders want, the shareholders can feel more at ease with getting rid of a president they don't agree with or feel has done a terrible job, without worrying that the company will tank.  Stock prices may even stabilise knowing that there is a steady professional hand in the background, despite being more shareholder active (i.e. democratic).

---

**political parties**

Political parties are organised through their respective nominating committee and overseen by the nominating commission.  Each seat may have as many candidates for that seat as there are political parties in the company.  Preferably the parties would be less big tent and more issue based (eg green, pirate, libertarian, rather than conservative).  Further, the parties can be corporate-oriented (eg environmentally friendly party, dividends every year party, reinvest annually party, R&D party, etc).

---

**review commission**

Shareholders chosen by lottery sit as a jury for in-house offences and review board or executive decisions for violating the charter and mission.  Similar to the corporate judicial branch.

Comment: The executive board would be the size of a modern corporate board (US, around 7-11).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: A founder could set up a special position with assent power and appointing the president and executive board, but similar to the Queen.

Comment: @community I'm asking if all corporations were required to do this, would the economy collapse, would economic democracy be realised, or another scenario?

Comment: This is very open-ended, quite speculative and might very well be better put to Stack Economics to debate the plus/minuses of governance models for companies, as it doesn't, directly, affect politics-within-a-country, province or municipality.  Not convinced it is a good fit here, but not casting close vote for now.  

But welcome aboard anyway.

Comment: I think this is too speculative to get useful answer.  For example define "corporation".  That could be anything from Google (now) to Google (in 1997).  Moreover, remember WTO doesn't make the law in any country....  So voting to close.

Comment: Agreed, I think this question is probably a bit too broad and speculative to be a good fit. It's an interesting idea though, and I wonder if something similar may have been explored in academia and could be looked at in an answer.

Comment: Please do not edit meta-commentary like "don't close my question again" into the question, and *especially* not in all-caps, because it's like you're yelling at us. If you object to the closing of your question, that's fine, but please *respectfully* [take it to Meta](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Any system of "political parties" within a company would be a good way to destroy it - creating factions who do everything they can to block the goals of the other factions.

Comment: @F1Krazy : no disrespect intended.  I apologise for my statement.  I was merely hoping for assistance in an edit to allow the question.  I attempted, but as you have noticed, I have failed.  I have transferred the question over to quora which is a bit more lenient.  Cheers.